# Python Dice Game Issue

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to learn more python, and am trying to created a dice game. My issue, is that when running it in IDLE, it loops after the initial yes to the input. Can anyone  give me some tips/help?

If I change

```
roll = input('Would you like to play a game?')
```

To

```
roll = "yes"
```

All it does start, and end the script immediately.

Here is my full code

```
import random

min = 0
max = 20

i = random.randint(min,max)

roll = input('Would you like to play a game?')

while roll == "yes":
    print ('''
======================================
You run into a deadly demonic intity.
You must role to save your life.
You must role higher than a 10 to win.
======================================
    ''')
    for i in range(1):
        print (random.randint(min,max))
        if i >= 10:
            print ('''Your staff begins to hum as you say your incantation.
The demonic intitiy, begins to shreak with a blood curtling sound.
You stand your ground, and banish it!''')
        elif i <= 10:
        print ('''You watch in dispair, as the intity devours your friends.
 You stand their, with no where to run, knowing that this is the end...''')
if roll == "no":
        print ('Guess you could run too...')
```

I am wanting it to grab the random.randint, and output the responding statement. I also noticed that even though it loops, it completes skips

```
if i >=10:
```

And just loops the reply for

```
elif i <=10:
```

Even if the random.randint is 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems:

1. You are conditioning on I which is always 0 or 1:

   for i in range(1):

This will always be 0 or 1.
Instead you should check the Actual dice roll for example:

```
dice_value=(random.randint(min,max))
```

2. Use raw input instead of input to grab a string and solve the nave error with you yes input.

This code works if you have any other question let me know:

```
import random
min = 0
max = 20

i = random.randint(min,max)

roll = raw_input('Would you like to play a game? ')

print (roll)

while roll == 'yes':
    print ('''
======================================
You run into a deadly demonic intity.
You must role to save your life.
You must role higher than a 10 to win.
======================================
    ''')
    dice_value=(random.randint(min,max))
    print ("You Rolled " + str(dice_value))

    if dice_value >= 10:
      print ('''Your staff begins to hum as you say your incantation.
The demonic intitiy, begins to shreak with a blood curtling sound.
You stand your ground, and banish it!''')
    elif dice_value <= 10:
      print ('''You watch in dispair, as the intity devours your friends.
 You stand their, with no where to run, knowing that this is the end...''')
    roll=raw_input('Roll Again?')
if roll == "no":
  print ('Guess you could run too...')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Using the code that you provided does work, though I have to use input, and not raw_input. The reason being, is 3.5.1 doesn't support raw_input anymore to my knowledge.